# Can Google track nested hashbang URLs?

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, hashbang

I've created a onepager website where google is able to track the ajax loaded content of the main site by loading each content via the !#my-url <-> _escaped_fragment_ "translation"
In one of those ajax loaded contents are some more hashbang URLs included for displaying/loading product data. Google not seems to read those 2nd level ajax content.

Is there a way to tell google to read such content??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

TBH I'm not 100% sure what you are asking here, perhaps update your question to give some more  details (more specific URL "this vs. this" examples, *what* you are wanting to track (a general page view? an event? etc..) but assuming you are just looking to track a page view, you can pop

`_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`

whenever you want, and you can keep calling it (for instance, inject it into your response from AJAX calls).  It also allows for an option 2nd element to the array you pass, to specify what you want the page name to be (by default if you don't specify, it is just the current URL):

`_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','whatever you want here']);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dont want to track that some user has loaded the AJAX content. I want that google knows that the AJAX loadable content exists. google is able to index the first level of my AJAX page requests identified by the #!hashbang-urls . But in some of my loaded content (products-page) are more #!hashbang-urls included. Google doesnt index this 2nd level pages for more possible hashbangs....but I want that google do so ;)

Comment: Aaah I see what you're saying, so this isn't really a GA question at all, it is a question about getting google to index pages.  I think google has a page where you can submit a list of urls for google to crawl, I'll post a separate answer with details